# Castle Windsor log4net facility throw exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net, castle-windsor, log4net-configuration

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project I use Castle Windsor library to resolve dependencies. 
Now installed Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor via Nuget.
I need logging feature, so I installed Castle.Windsor-log4net Nuget package.

I try to register log4net facility for future resolving in my controllers and get exception:

```
public class ContainerFactory
{
    private static IWindsorContainer container;
    private static readonly object SyncObject = new object();

    public static IWindsorContainer Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                container = new WindsorContainer();
                // run some installers here
                container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net()); //Exception here
            }

            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

> An exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.ConverterException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not convert string 'Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.Log4netFactory,Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' to a type.

Now in my web project referenced next assemblies:
Castle.Core v 4.0.0
Castle.Windsor v 4.0.0
Castle.Facilities.Logging v 4.0.0
Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration v 3.3.0.0

I configured log4net with next config:

```
<log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="Logs\Application.log" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d  %-5p %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <logger name="LOGGER">
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

and section

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
```

Is this good configuration, or problem not in it?
How can I fix this exception?

Comment: Problably some dll clashes your program searches for Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration,Version=4.0.0.0, but you have 3.3.0.0 referenced.